# What is the real sequence of work of the catch block and the resource closing?

Tags: java, resources, try-with-resources

In [Oracle Java documentation on try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) there is written the following:

> A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just
>   like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any
>   catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been
>   closed.

So, according to the documentation, if an exception happens while trying to close the resource, and I am honestly trying to react somehow on that sad piece of news, as here:

```
try (OutputStream os = new SampleStream(true)) {
  os.write(0); // both this and closing can throw IOWriteException 
} 
catch (IOWriteException e) {
    //do something wise;
}
```

at problem with closing, the catch block will wait for closing forever.

I know, that really it is not so, and the try-with-resources exception on closing can be caught. But then the rule mentioned should be reformulated. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know, that really it is not so, and the try-with-resources exception
>   on closing can be caught.

Right and also on initialization of the resource.

I think that [the extended try-with-resources part of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2) could help to reformulate this quite awkward explanation.
While it is rather right for the part concerning the `finally` statement.

We could say that :

A `catch` statement in a try-with-resources statement allows to catch a compatible exception thrown in any part of this statement, that is **1)during the resource initialization, 2)during the resource closing of any resource or 3)by statements executed in the try-with-resources body**.
Concerning the `finally` statement, **it will be executed after resources  were closed** (or attempted to be).

Reference :

> 14.20.3.2. Extended try-with-resources
>
> A try-with-resources statement with at least one `catch` clause and/or a
>   `finally` clause is called an extended try-with-resources statement.
>
> The meaning of an extended try-with-resources statement:

```
try ResourceSpecification
    Block
Catchesopt
Finallyopt
```

> is given by the following translation to a basic try-with-resources
>   statement (§14.20.3.1) nested inside a `try-catch` or `try-finally` or
>   `try-catch-finally` statement:

```
try {
    try ResourceSpecification
        Block
}
Catchesopt
Finallyopt
```

> The effect of the translation is to put the `ResourceSpecification`
>   "inside" the `try` statement. This allows a `catch` clause of an extended
>   try-with-resources statement to catch an exception due to the
>   automatic initialization or closing of any resource.
>
> Furthermore, all resources will have been closed (or attempted to be
>   closed) by the time the `finally` block is executed, in keeping with the
>   intent of the `finally` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting reference and an upvote. But I think, the correct answer to my question will be the explanation after the code in the previous paragraph 14.20.3.1. Basic try-with-resources. The piece starts with: "In a basic try-with-resources statement that manages a single resource:" A very thorough explanation of all cases follows.

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure that this part be enough because a "basic try-with-resources" statement is a  try-with-resources without any explicit `catch` or `finally` statement and actually your question concerns the extended try-with-resources.

Comment: Yes. The full answer simply needs both parts. But as I have already what I want, I marked your answer as such.... But I do not understand why docs on that theme are so thinly spread among different paragraphs and even documents.

Comment: @Gangnus I agree. JLS is a very good source of information but finding a specific information in may sometimes be complicated...

Comment: @Gangnus - The reason is that the JLS is not designed with the primary goal of being easy to read.  The primary goals are technical accuracy and completeness, and the primary audience is "people who write Java compilers" and similar tools.  So in many places the JLS is terse and uses language that borders on being mathematical.  If you are looking for an easy to read / easy to understand explanation, the first place to look is the Oracle Java Tutorial.

Comment: In this particular case, the spec writers thought it would be easier and more concise to specify the more advanced forms of `try` in terms of the simpler ones.  This approach also has the advantage that there is less room for mistakes and ambiguity.   This makes the spec less readable ... but that is not the primary goal.

Comment: @StephenC If you look at the question,you'll notice, that the problem started from incorrect explanation in the usual documentation. As for JLS, it is much better and I have nothing against strict language. But that does not explain the incorrect and weak explanations in the "usual" documentation. How a developer will know that the correct answer is somewhere else? As a result, I had NEVER seen before a single example of correct work with exceptions on closing in a real project.

Comment: Well perhaps you should raise this with the people who really matter; i.e. the people who can fix the problem.